# Summarizing across multiple search strings in R using grepl and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I have a rather unorganized dataframe which has varying names for the same categories in one column. I want to summarize across those messy names using dplyr.

Here's a simplified dataset, of tree species and their traits:

```
df <- data.frame(species = c('sp1', 'sp1', 'sp1', 'sp2', 'sp2'), tr = c('leaf nitrogen per mass', 'wood den', 'nitrogen (per mass)', 'leaf carbon per area', 'wood dens'), val = sample(1:10, 5), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

So each species has a number of trait values of different categories in this dataset.

You can get summary statistics per species using dplyr and the code below.

```
library(dplyr)
by_sp<- df %>% 
group_by(species, tr)

by_sp %>% summarize(avg = mean(val))
```

You can see that it treats the same traits as separate, since they don't match completely. I want to summarize across these using fuzzy matching for many different traits, but don't know how to implement this across many traits at the same time. So far I have tried using grepl to create a vector of 'required' strings to filter by. Ex.

```
lmass <- 'nitrogen|mass'
by_sp %>% filter(grepl(lmass, tr, ignore.case=T)) %>% summarize(ave = mean(val))
```

But this is using 'or', whereas I want 'and'- requiring both strings, so that the final dataframe is a single average across all rows containing both nitrogen and mass (in column tr).

Additionally I have many of these trait strings, and I want a dataframe at the end with averages for each of these traits per species. So far I have tried combining the different search strings, but this doesn't work.

```
wood <- 'wood den' #this could have other keywords required for this trait
alltr <- c(lmass, wood)
leaf_tr %>% filter(grepl(alltr, tr, ignore.case=T)) %>% summarize(ave = mean(val)) #gives an error, only takes first element in alltr
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a data.table solution.  I know you're asking for `dplyr`, but unfortunately some of the issues I ran into exceeded my `dplyr` skills (e.g. create multiple columns with `mutate`):

```
# setup regular expressions, etc.

library(data.table); library(reshape2)    
traits <- c(nm="nitrogen.*mass", wd="wood den", ca="carbon.*area")
trait.nm <- names(traits)
DT <- data.table(df)  # make data table

DT[,  # Add a column for each trait, indicating whether row matches the trait
  c(trait.nm):=
    data.frame(sapply(trait.nm, function(x) grepl(traits[x], tr)))
]    
melt(DT, id.vars=names(df))[           # transform to long format
  value == TRUE,                       # filter for trait-val combinations that match  
  sum(val), by=.(species, variable)    # group by standardized trait
]
```

This produces:

```
   species variable V1
1:     sp1       nm 13
2:     sp1       wd  3
3:     sp2       wd  1
4:     sp2       ca  2
```

Note I added the "Carbon Area" category.  In order to solve your "OR" problem with nitrogen mass, I just changed the regular expression to `"nitrogen.*mass"`.

One big caveat with this is you need to make sure that each trait can only match one regular expression, otherwise you will end up with the trait counted multiple times in different trait categories.

Comment: Thanks Brodie- I definitely agree with your caveat. It's the whole reason I need this multiple string matching. I ran into a few issues trying to implement your code. First I tried changing the regular expression and using it in dplyr, with 'nitrogen.*mass', but it still doesn't average across the 'leaf nitrogen per mass' and 'nitrogen (per mass)' categories. It seems odd to me that it would work with data.table but not dplyr.

Comment: Additionally, I think there might be an issue with the '.' in the melt index. My run threw up an error, but if you change 'by=.()' to 'by=list()' it goes.

Comment: @the `by=.()` is implemented in newer versions of data table, so that might be the problem you are running into.  It is an alias for `list()`

Comment: Great, updated and it works! I'd still like to keep this in dplyr, as I have other code I need to run that are quite intuitive with that package, but it's nice to have this as an option.